# Does this notation mean the product of a matrix and a set?

Tags: definition, convex-optimization

> Let $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a convex function.
>
> Define $\text{epi}(f)=\{(x,t) | f(x) \le t\}$.
>
> If $w \ge 0$ then $\text{epi}(wf) = \left[
> \begin{array}{cc}
>   I&0\\
>   0&w
> \end{array}
> \right] \text{epi}(f)$ is
>   convex.

What does the notation $\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  I&0\\
  0&w
\end{array}
\right] \text{epi}(f)$ mean?  It looks like the product of a matrix and a set.  Can someone explain what this notation means and why these two things are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply mat multiply to each point of the set: $M(x,t)^T$.

Comment: What set is $M$?

Comment: It's the matrix. And $(x,t) \in epi(f)$.

Comment: So $M \space \text{epi}(f)$ is a set?

Comment: Yes $Mepi(f) = \{(x,t)M^T : f(x) \leq t\}$.

Comment: So since in this case $M(x,t)^T = (x,wt)$, then $M \space \text{epi}(f) = \{(x, wt) : (x,t) \in \text{epi}(f)\}$?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Note that $(x,wt)$ is a row vector so you need $(x,t)M^T$ and not vice versa. Though for a diagonal matrix it does not matter.

Comment: Actually it matters, you want a $1 \times 2$ vector, not a $2 \times 1$. The statement is trivial after you understand the notation.